# Blade in wordpress plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-blade

Is it possible to integrate laravel's Blade coding style for plugin development in wordpress?

If so, can anyone illustrate the procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use this library to use Blade in any PHP project: https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade

The github page also gives you details on how to get started with the library

Comment: For templating, no doubt, it can be used.. But i need the coding style of blade for plugin development as well... thats why asked.. thanks for the reference.. i'll check and revert back...

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the blade plugin for wordpress which can be downloaded from - https://wordpress.org/plugins/blade/

Comment: For templating, no doubt, it can be used.. But i need the coding style of blade for plugin development as well... thats why asked..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout this package https://github.com/laraish/laraish